# facebook feed template: right alignment for text

Tags: facebook, fbml

I'm trying to make my text right aligned in my feed template, but it seems that FBML does not support a div tag in feed body. how can I make my text right aligned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to align text in feed templates, the only way I can think of that may work is if you added several transparent images to your template and they could push the text to the right slightly,

Hope that helps.